# Get JSTL to work with Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jstl

I can't figure this one out. I tested my application in glassfish, and everything works fine. But when I deploy to a tomcat server, it is having trouble with the jstl in my jsp. It is pointing to this line.

```
<c:when test="${empty reservations}">
```

I don't understand what the difference is with Tomcat. Any ideas? The exact message is:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /results.jsp   at line 20 17:
```

Do I have to have the jstl jar in both my lib directory, and the lib directory in tomcat?

Comment: Isn't there more to that error message? Doesn't it show a root cause?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an entry at top,

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

Also, keep jstl jar inside lib folder (WEB-INF -> lib folder), if you are running through Eclipse, then keep it at Build Path as well for solving Messages it shows(as Eclipse IDE will refer from Build Path).

If trying through Eclipse, then just check this folder,

```
   Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\ProjectName
```

check here "ProjectName" contains that jstl jar or not.